# Call function to new window/tab then redirect to other function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a report with fpdf. My problem is I want to call the function that using fpdf class in new window after processing save to database, like this:
I can figure like this
1. First I have to save to the database, with the data posted form form html.
2. Call fpdf function to print the result with the same data with the first process.
3. redirect to index function to show that data has been saved into database.

my code like this :

```
//save to database
$this->My_model->insert($data);

//call the pdf function
$this->print_the_result($data);

//redirect
redirect('my_class/index');
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a really hard time understanding your question. But if you want to process the form in a new window you could do <form ... target="_blank">. And to do a redirect header('location:index.php'); Sorry if I am completely wrong with my answer as I found it hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

Redirection by Codeigniter only works within the window it operates with, as the server does not know anything about the client (the browser).

The (generally explained) workaround is explained at http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/110435/#557038:

"You will need to send them to a page with HTML output that uses JavaScript to open the new window"

With that being said, you might need some help from the your View module to do the redirection.

Comment: Exactly. Save it to your DB, then display confirmation message with a link pointing to another action which display pdf.